# Consulta mysql para sacar el maximo de temperatura del día y la fecha que fue esa maxima temperatura con datetime

Tags: mysql

ESTA ES MI CONSULTA

```
SELECT id_bodega , MAX(temperatura),MAX (fecha) FROM bodegas WHERE DATE(fecha) = DATE( NOW()) GROUP BY id_bodega;
```

Answer (score 0):

El SQL, y concretamente el `GROUP BY`, no funciona así, sino de esta otra forma:

```
SELECT * FROM bodegas JOIN (
    SELECT id_bodega,
      MAX(temperatura) temperatura
      FROM bodegas
      WHERE DATE(fecha) = DATE(NOW())
      GROUP BY id_bodega
  ) c1 USING(id_bodega,temperatura);
```

Pruébala y déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para completar la respuesta.